# Robot Framework how to use FOR loop for a specific column in a table

Tags: for-loop, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to know how to use a FOR loop for a specific column in a table.
Basically. I want to get the text in the third column and equate / verify it to be "LOCAL" for all rows. I will provide a basic diagram of the table

[image]

So, in the diagram the checkboxes take up as first table cell and the top row is a table header.
What i want is to get the text of all the cells under column /th4 and equate it to be as "LOCAL" as said before. There might be multiple entries and will be dynamic. So, that is why i want to use FOR loop.

PS: every cell under /th4 is LOCAL , so just want to equate the text.

My code:

```
Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="selectType"]/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li/div   
Sleep    0.1    
Click Element    class=dropdown-btn  
Sleep    0.1
Click Button    id=filterBtn
Sleep    0.1    
Click Element    id=closeFilter   
Table Row Should Contain    xpath=//*[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span    1    LOCAL
Table Row Should Contain    xpath=//*[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/span    2    LOCAL
Table Row Should Contain    xpath=//*[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/span    3    LOCAL
```

Basically, there is filter option... once i filter, the fourth /td in the table will all contain text "LOCAL".
Instead of me manually typing "table row should contain" keyword, i want to for loop it to verify all the cells in that column

Let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks and Regards,
Sandesh K S

Comment: Yes, more information required. Please add the `code` that you tried so far ?

Comment: Please share your code that you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sure. Please see the updated query.

Answer (score 0):

For loop is not the best option here because you usually need to know beforehand how many elements you have and you mention that number of rows can change. It would be better to use while loop:

```
${row}=    Set Variable    1
WHILE   True
    ${elements}=      xpath=//*[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr[${row}]/td[4]/span
    ${num_elements}=  Get Length    ${elements}
    IF           '${elements}' == '0'
         BREAK
    END
    Table Row Should Contain    xpath=//*[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr[${row}]/td[4]/span    1    LOCAL
    ${row}=    Evaluate    ${row} + 1
END
```

Comment: I am getting an error with this code on the WHILE loop. It says "'While' is a reserved keyword."  Plus, the 
${elements}=      xpath=//*[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr[${row}]/td[4]/span
is throwing "unknown keyword"

Comment: Hi, can you add your new code to your question?